# Monolog has no permission to write on OSX

Tags: php, macos, permissions, monolog

I'm using the built-in php server to setup a server for my slim project, using `php -S localhost:8000`

Now I've included Monolog with the default config.
Whenver I try to write using Monolog I get the following error

```
There is no existing directory at "/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Read-only file system in /Users/miguel/Code/strava-php/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 172
```

This is the result of `stat storage`, showing my current folder permissions.

> 31361802 drwxrwxrwx 3 miguel staff 0 96 "Aug 16 12:54:22 2020" "Aug 16 12:54:22 2020" "Aug 16 13:08:57 2020" "Aug 16 12:49:30 2020" 4096 0 0 storage

#### What I've tried

- Use `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs`
- Use `chown miguel storage/logs`

Answer (score 0):

I think giving permission on the `storage` folder will solve the problem instead of giving permission only on the `logs` folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```